# How to vertically center images on article list?

Tags: css, sass

I have a problem with an article/tutorial list with my project.

[Scenario](http://codepen.io/makmm/pen/ZLpzdQ) (images can be other sizes instead of 256x256, but must be square, cant use background trick because I'm using handlebars on server, image doesn't need to be with `position: absolute`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.tutorial {
    background-color: #ccc;
    position: relative;
    img {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        margin: auto 0;
    }
...
```

The

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
margin: auto 0;
```

is what makes it vertically centered.

The `position: relative;` on `.tutorial` is what makes the `img` vertically centered against. Otherwise it'd vertically centered on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by changing `img` css from:

```
img {
        position: absolute;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        float: left;
    }
```

to:

```
img {
        position: relative;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translateY(-50%);
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        float: left;
    }
```

Adding `position: relative`, `top:50%` and transform: `translateY(-50%)` is a very effective way to center elements vertically.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with JS.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="tutorial" id="tutorial">
            <img src="http://www.iconshock.com/img_jpg/BETA/mail_icons/jpg/256/template_icon.jpg" alt="image" id="img"/>
            <div class="text">
                <header>
                    <h1>lorem ipsum</h1>
                    <span>
                        by: who knows?
                    </span>
                </header>
                <p>
                    description bla bla bla bla
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the JS-part:

```
var tutorialId = document.getElementById("tutorial");
var heightTutorial = tutorialId.offsetHeight;
var imgId = document.getElementById("img");
var heightImg = imgId.offsetHeight;
var margin = (heightTutorial-heightImg);
imgId.style.marginTop=margin/2+'px';
```

If you change the height of the tutorial afterwards, you have to call the JS again.